# How to format the currency using Intl.NumberFormat?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to format the currency as following

```
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-GB", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "GBP",
    minimumFractionDigits: 2
  });

const moneyFormat = formatter.format(7360);
```

Expected `£73.60` but it returns `£7,360.00`

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why did you expect `£73.60`? The value is `7360`, not `73.60`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe the number is returned from mangoPay which is not adding any commas. So the actual value is 73.60 but is returned as 7360 so I want to display accordingly

Comment: What do you mean *"not adding any commas"*? It's a *number*. If you're receiving pennies and need to display pounds, you need to divide it.

Comment: For anyone who doesn't understand why this is an **excellent question**, read about floats and money: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency
... Unfortunately, `Intl.NumberFormat()` does not have something like a `minorUnits: true` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `format` function takes the raw value and will format it to the amount of fraction digits that you specify. The raw number you gave it was `7360`, so it is adding two fraction digits to make it `7360.00`. The number it needs to be passed is actually `73.60`.

If you are working with the currency value as the whole number, you can simply divide by 100 to display the value you are expecting.

```
const moneyFormat = formatter.format(7360 / 100);
```

Comment: decimal value is still showing ... can i know how to avoid it in this case

Answer (score 2):

If the amount is in `pence` and the result required in GBP, you have to divide the amount by 100, (considering 100 pence = 1 GBP). The `minimumFractionDigits` adjust the trailing Zeros after decimal point of the currently but does not manipulate the actual value.

You should try below

```js
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-GB", {
  style: "currency",
  currency: "GBP",
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
});

const moneyFormat = formatter.format(7360 / 100);

console.log(moneyFormat)
```

Answer (score 0):

> this code might help you to attain the format without decimal.

```js
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-GB", {
    currency: "GBP"
  });

const moneyFormat = formatter.format(7360);

console.log("$",moneyFormat);
```